# Set a property in EXTJS button from model

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have the following button in EXTJS in the view

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'ACCOUNTS-3',
    action: 'popup',
}
```

I want to set a new property to this button which is going to be a field from the model. I am not able to find a property in xtype:button.

Is there any way a property can be set which can be used in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just set any property, and you can access it later. Use console.log() to look at the object in Chrome Developper Tools.

You should be able to access the object from which the button was created through `button.initialConfig`.

```
var button = Ext.create({
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'ACCOUNTS-3',
    action: 'popup',
    customProperty: 'test
})
console.log(button.initialConfig)
```

This will log the following in the console:

```
{
    text: 'ACCOUNTS-3',
    action: 'popup',
    customProperty: 'test
}
```